# Number of pivot columns just by looking at the matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, matrix-rank

Suppose I have the matrix: 
$$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 & 1 \\
    1 & 1 & 2 & 1 \\
    1 & 2 & 3 & 1\\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

How do I figure out the number of pivot columns in its ref by using the fact that it's $3^{rd}$ and $4^{th}$ are are dependent on columns on $1$ and $2$. Please assume that the concepts of dimension and rank have not yet been introduced in the course. I wish to get an intuitive understanding.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to determine the number of pivot columns without thinking about dimension and rank, then I would think about what happens when you row-reduce this matrix (i.e., look at the rows, not the columns). There can be no more than $3$ pivot columns, since there are only $3$ rows which could have leading entries. Since the third row is identical to the first, it will be zeroed out and will not have a leading entry. The first and second rows are not multiples of each other, though, so they should both end up with a leading entry. Hence there will be two pivot columns.

Comment: Thanks, so nothing can be concluded from just the columns and their linear dependence?

Comment: By looking at the columns, you can conclude that there are two linearly independent columns (the second and the third are linearly independent, while the first and fourth can be written in terms of them). However, without any notion of dimension or rank, I don't think it's "intuitively" clear what that has to do with the number of pivot columns. (The number of linearly independent columns will be equal to the number of pivot columns, though.)

Comment: @Archer In order to conclude this from the columns and their linear independence, you need to use concepts of dimension and rank (which you are specifically excluding).